# Time remaining from NSProgressIndicator

Tags: cocoa

I am developing an application in cocoa,I need to calculate the time remaining from NSProgressIndicator .Is that posiible???

Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 2):

This is a "how long is a piece of string" question. Without knowing more about what your app is doing, there is no way we can answer it sufficiently.

You are responsible for updating the progress indicator to give the user an idea of how far through a task you are. How you obtain that information (if it is obtainable) will determine how you update the progress indicator.

Answer (score 2):

A progress indicator has no concept of time. If it isn't indeterminate, it has a minimum value, current value, and maximum value. That's pretty much it.

Tracking the current value, the time you're taking, and your estimate for how long you have yet to take is your job.